# The table filter data is not working while working with BS4 in python

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch data from the page:

http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#club/CD_T20

but after getting the data it's not what I need. 
I have set the club filter value to "Brisbane Lions" but when the page is fetched, the obtained data is in a way as it would have been if "All" (instead of "Brisbane Lions") was selected.

Can you let me know where the mistake I am committing.

Answer (score 0):

The page uses JavaScript to parse the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) on the URL.

Your browser doesn't actually send the `#club/CD_T20` portion, only the path section (`/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings`) is ever received by the server. A such, the HTML returned includes *all* teams, *always*.

The Javascript code filters what rows in the table are visible only after the HTML has been loaded from the server.